# Python: How to preserve Ä,Ö,Ü when writing to file

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I open 2 files in Python, change and replace some of their content and write the new output into a 3rd file.
My 2 input files are XMLs, encoded in 'UTF-8 without BOM' and they have German Ä,Ö,Ü and ß in them. 
When I open my output XML file in Notepad++, the encoding is not specified (i.e. there's no encoding checked in the 'Encoding' tab). My Ä,Ö,Ü and ß are transformed into something like

```
&#252;
```

When I create the output in Python, I use

```
with open('file', 'w') as fout:
  fout.write(etree.tostring(tree.getroot()).decode('utf-8'))
```

What do I have to do instead?

Comment: When writing to a file, you want to `encode`, not `decode`.

Comment: The question is whether the `&#252;` is not only the Notepad++ way to display the characters outside ASCII when working with XML file, or whether the sequence is inside the input file. See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/11539528/1346705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some explanation for the `xml.etree.ElementTree` for Python 2, and for its function `parse()`. The function takes the source as the first argument. Or it can be an open file object, or it can be a filename. The function creates the `ElementTree` instance, and then it passes the argument to the `tree.parse(...)` that looks like this:

```
def parse(self, source, parser=None):
    if not hasattr(source, "read"):
        source = open(source, "rb")
    if not parser:
        parser = XMLParser(target=TreeBuilder())
    while 1:
        data = source.read(65536)
        if not data:
            break
        parser.feed(data)
    self._root = parser.close()
    return self._root
```

You can guess from the third line that if the filename was passed, the file is opened in binary mode. This way, if the file content was in UTF-8, you are processing elements with UTF-8 encoded binary content. If this is the case, you should **open also the output file in binary mode**.

Another possibility is to use `codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8')` for opening the input file, and passing the open file object to the `xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(...)`. This way, the `ElementTree` instance will **work with Unicode strings**, and you should encode the result to UTF-8 when writing the content back. If this is the case, you can use **`codecs.open(...)` with UTF-8 also for writing**. You can pass the opened output file object to the mentioned `tree.write(f)`, **or** you let the **`tree.write(filename, encoding='utf-8')`** open the file for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
import codecs

with codecs.open("file.xml", 'w', "utf-8") as fout:
    # do stuff with filepointer
```

Comment: In my case, this returned a "TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly"

Answer (score 2):

When writing raw bytestrings, you want to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open('file', 'wb') as fout:
    fout.write(xyz)
```

Otherwise the [`open` call](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#open) opens the file in text mode and expects unicode strings instead, and will encode them for you.

To decode, is to interpret an encoding (like utf-8) and the output is unicode text. If you do want to decode first, specify an encoding when opening the file in text mode:

```
with open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.write(xyz.decode('utf-8'))
```

If you don't specify an encoding Python will use a default, which usually is a Bad Thing. Note that since you are already *have* UTF-8 encoded byte strings to start with, this is actually useless.

Note that python file operations never transform existing unicode points to [XML character entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) (such as `&#252;`), other code you have could do this but you didn't share that with us.

I found [Joel Spolsky's article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) invaluable when it comes to understanding encodings and unicode.

Comment: if `xyz` is already a bytestring then `xyz.encode` might corrupt it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Of course, but decoding isn't going to help in that case either. We know too little of the OP's code to answer this properly in any case; the `decode` feels like the OP is whacking at a a problem without understanding, hence the link to the Unicode article.

Comment: I received an "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'". I adjusted my code a bit to make it more specific.

Comment: If you already have a bytestring there is no need to encode (nor decode).

Comment: I am confused. If I use decode, my stuff gets actually written into the output file. But if I use nothing, I receive "TypeError: must be str, not bytes".

Comment: Ah, python 3. Open as binary or specify an encoding. Updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Mhh...I tried both options now, and they gave me an output, but I still have these weird characters instead of my Ä,Ö,Ü...

Comment: The 'weird characters' are [XML character entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) and are valid XML elements.

Comment: Yes, but since I didn't have them in my input file, I also don't want them in my output file and I still don't understand how to get rid of them.

Comment: In which case we need to know how you process your input file. It's not the write operation that does this in any case. Make it a new question.

Answer (score 2):

To write an `ElementTree` object `tree` to a file named `'file'` using the `'utf-8'` character encoding:

```
tree.write('file', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: It may depend on how the input file was opened. See my comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/11539528/1346705. I am not sure here, but it may work for yo by accident.

Comment: @pepr: `'file'` is not a file object, but a file name here. `ElementTree` takes care about it by itself. No accident here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I have noticed that. But in the case the `ElementTree` opens the file in binary mode. See my comment.

Comment: @pepr: the code in my answer works as is. It doesn't depend on anything. Judging by the fact that you've included it in your answer, you might also believe that it works.